# Confirmation password issue in MVC3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I use the following model to control user input and to register him.
But if I input the same passwords and press a button **the message about that confirmation password is wrong appears.**

I am sure about the model is correct because it works in some other page.
In this case **RegisterModelSecond** is a member of **EventFrontEndViewModel**.

So when I comment `[Compare("RegisterModel.Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]` it works but no confirmation I need!

Any clue how to fix it?

```
public class EventFrontEndViewModel
    {
        public Page CurrentPage { set; get; }

        public List<Event> Events { set; get; }

        public List<Event> SubscribedEvents { set; get; }

        public RegisterModelSecond RegisterModel { set; get; }

        public EventFrontEndViewModel()
        {
            CurrentPage = new Page();
            Events = new List<Event>();
            RegisterModel = new RegisterModelSecond();
            SubscribedEvents = new List<Event>();
        }
    }
```

Register Model

```
public class RegisterModelSecond
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

and HTML

```
<div class="editor-label">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Password)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="editor-field">
                                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Password)
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegisterModel.Password)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="editor-label">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RegisterModel.ConfirmPassword)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="editor-field">
                                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.RegisterModel.ConfirmPassword)
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RegisterModel.ConfirmPassword)
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear">
                                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found correct answer here [MVC 3 Client-Side Compare Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713872/mvc-3-client-side-compare-validation)

This is a bug in the client side validation script: jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

At Line ~284 you'll find this:

```
element = $(options.form).find(":input[name=" + fullOtherName + "]")[0];
```

Change it to this:

```
element = $(options.form).find(":input[name='" + fullOtherName + "']")[0];
```

The name attribute needs single quotes.

---

I want to add if you use MIN version u have to change it there as well.